# Standard way of reconnecting to webSocket server in redux-Saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, websocket, redux-saga

I'm trying to connect from my **react App** to **websocket** server using **redux-saga** and want to capture the connection loss (server error, reboot) so that to reconnect say in intervals of 4 seconds until the connection is again back. The problem is on reconnecting to webSocket the **redux store does not get updated anymore.**

I tried using **eventChannel** of redux-saga as per following code. Unfortunately there was not or at least I couldn't find any documentation answering **ws reconnect in redux-saga**.

```js
import {eventChannel} from 'redux-saga';
import {all, takeEvery, put, call, take, fork} from 'redux-saga/effects'
import {INITIALIZE_WS_CHANNEL} from "../../constants/ActionTypes"
import {updateMarketData} from "../actions"


function createEventChannel() {
    return eventChannel(emit => {

        //Subscribe to websocket
        const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9000/rates');

        ws.onopen = () => {
            console.log("Opening Websocket");
        };

        ws.onerror = error => {
            console.log("ERROR: ", error);
        };

        ws.onmessage = e => {
            return emit({data: JSON.parse(e.data)})
        };

        ws.onclose = e => {
            if (e.code === 1005) {
                console.log("WebSocket: closed");
            } else {
                console.log('Socket is closed Unexpectedly. Reconnect will be attempted in 4 second.', e.reason);
                setTimeout(() =>  {
                    createEventChannel();
                }, 4000);
            }
        };

        return () => {
            console.log("Closing Websocket");
            ws.close();
        };
    });
}

function * initializeWebSocketsChannel() {
    const channel = yield call(createEventChannel);
    while (true) {
        const {data} = yield take(channel);
        yield put(updateMarketData(data));
    }
}

export function * initWebSocket() {
    yield takeEvery(INITIALIZE_WS_CHANNEL, initializeWebSocketsChannel);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all ([
        fork(initWebSocket)
    ]);
}
```

---

***UPDATE***

To complete the accepted answer by @azundo for someone looking for a complete example of websocket & redux-saga I'm adding following code:

```
function * initializeWebSocketsChannel() {
    console.log("going to connect to WS")
    const channel = yield call(createEventChannel);
    while (true) {
        const {data} = yield take(channel);
        yield put(updateMarketData(data));
    }
}

export function * startStopChannel() {
    while (true) {
        yield take(START_CHANNEL);
        yield race({
            task: call(initializeWebSocketsChannel),
            cancel: take(STOP_CHANNEL),
        });
        //if cancel wins the race we can close socket
        ws.close();
    }
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all ([
        startStopChannel()
    ]);
}
```

---

The ***START_CHANNEL*** and ***STOP_CHANNEL*** actions can be called in ***componentDidMount*** and ***componentWillUnmount*** of react component life cycle, respectively.

Comment: I saw your answer and it sounds to be a good idea to be used with componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount, but what if we disconnect on componentDidMount and after some time we want to connect again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because your recursive call to `createEventChannel` is not being `yield`ed to the saga middleware `redux-saga` has no way of knowing of the subsequent event channel creations. You'll want your recursive function to be defined within the event channel instead, see code below, so there is only one `eventChannel` that is always hooked into the store.

Also note the addition of emitting END on an expected socket close so that you don't leave the eventChannel open forever if you don't reconnect.

```
import {eventChannel, END} from 'redux-saga';

let ws; //define it here so it's available in return function

function createEventChannel() {
    return eventChannel(emit => {
          function createWs() {
            //Subscribe to websocket
            ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9000/rates');

            ws.onopen = () => {
                console.log("Opening Websocket");
            };

            ws.onerror = error => {
                console.log("ERROR: ", error);
            };

            ws.onmessage = e => {
                return emit({data: JSON.parse(e.data)})
            };

            ws.onclose = e => {
                if (e.code === 1005) {
                    console.log("WebSocket: closed");
                    // you probably want to end the channel in this case
                    emit(END);
                } else {
                    console.log('Socket is closed Unexpectedly. Reconnect will be attempted in 4 second.', e.reason);
                    setTimeout(() =>  {
                        createWs();
                    }, 4000);
                }
            };
        }
        createWs();

        return () => {
            console.log("Closing Websocket");
            ws.close();
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: one issue that I am facing is how would you implement the send logic with this code?
we need a callback or function which returns the socket object once connected.

Comment: If you just need singleton access one somewhat hacky option would be to export a `getWebsocketSingleton` function that returns the internal `ws`. You could set `ws = null;` at the top of the module and in the cleanup in that case and then check for `ws === null` before running `ws.send` elsewhere. Not sure if there's a better way to expose the websocket if using an event channel solution like this.